# Querying array of nested objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to query an array of objects.
I'm expecting to get the document below, but I'm getting nothing instead.

This is the collection:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5ef1714fc77dd22599054c8d")
        "surveyName": 'Sample',
        "participants": [
            {
                "name": 'John'
                "answers": {
                    'question1': 'abc',
                    'question2': 'def'
                }
            },
            {
                "name": 'Paul'
                "answers": {
                    'question1': 'def',
                    'question2': 'abc'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
db.surveys.find({
    _id: ObjectId("5ef1714fc77dd22599054c8d"),
    'participants.answers': { 
        '$elemMatch': { 
            '$or': [ 
                {'question1': 'abc'},
                {'question2': 'def'}
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Result:

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 22ms
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have two `question1`  in OR condition.

Comment: Ops, corrected that, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about avoiding element match and do this instead?

```js
db.surveys.find({
    $or: [{"participants.answers.question1":"abc"}, {"participants.answers.question2":"xyz"}]
})
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! Any idea why $elemMatch doesn't work in that case?